# How could one can say that frequency spectrum having Nyquist frequency 'x' is the most appropriate representation of a given signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform

I have a sinusoidal signal which has  a period of 2 and I want to find the frequencies that are present.I assumed sampling interval as 0.01 and based on this I sampled the signal.The Nyquist frequency i got from this is suppose 'x'.Now if I change my sampling interval to 0.001, Nyquist frequency in this case is '10*x'
So my question is,which frequency spectrum will represent the signal correctly, the one with Nyquist frequency 'x' or the one one with Nyquist frequency '10*x'

Comment: Why is your sampling interval so small? Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is to sample at more than twice your signal's *bandwidth*; the period is largely irrelevant. Say your signal with period 2 is a square wave -- its bandwidth is infinite and you'll never be able to sample it correctly (at least in theory). If your signal is a sine wave, then a period of 2 means its bandwidth is 0.5 and you'll easily sample it adequately.

Personally, whenever possible, I'd sample:

- a bit above Nyquist (say, at $2.2B$, where $B$ is the signal bandwidth), to maximize the number of useful frequency bins, and
- for as long as possible, to increase the spectral resolution.

Comment: i don't think using 2.2 to calculate the nyquist criterion is going to get this guy the correct answer to his homework question

Comment: The only thing that I know about my signal is the lowest frequency and the period.So bandwidth concept won't work in my case.

Comment: that is false. you know a lot about the available bandwidth given the sampling period.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about bandwidth.is there any other way?

Comment: what does your textbook say about the relationship between sampling period and sampling rate? and then what about the available bandwidth given the sampling rate?

Comment: sampling rate=1/sampling interval This is what i read in DFT. I am not from signal processing field so I don't know about the bandwidth.Can you refer me some book.

Comment: if you're asking what the signal's bandwidth is given $T=2$, you can't know unless you know what the signal is (i.e. is it a sinusoid, triangle, square pulse, etc.).

Comment: if on the other hand you are asking for the minimum rate at which you need to sample a sinusoid, you must sample at least twice greatest the frequency (which is $2\cdot Fs = 2 \cdot 1/T = 1$)

Comment: its a sinusoidal signal

Comment: T should be sampling interval not the period of the signal.So if sampling interval is 0.01 then greatest freq will be 1/(2*0.01)

Comment: @ashusharma, Please edit your question with the information that the signal is sinusoidal. For such a signal, the bandwidth is equal to $1/T$, or 0.5 Hz in your example. As long as your sampling frequency is larger than $2*0.5=1$ Hz, you're fine.

Comment: @MBaz But if I want to detect frequency smaller than 1 Hz then what can I do.Can you refer me any book regarding this

Comment: @ashusharma Read my answer: sample for a long time, and you'll get high frequency resolution. Any book on discrete signal processing will cover this; A. Openheim's is good.

Comment: your signal is smaller than 1 Hz, it's 1/2 Hz, so you need to sample at 1 Hz or greater. if your signal was sinusoidal and 1/4 Hz, you would need to sample at 1/2 Hz. do you see where this is going?

Comment: @ MBaz @ panthyon What I have done till know is that I assume sampling interval like si=0.01, then sampling freq =1/0.01  so my sampling freq is greater than 1Hz. Using Period and  sampling interval I determine the no. of sample points and to increase the frequency resolution I have added zeroes to the right of sampled data. So what i have done till know seems correct.Can commen on this please?

Comment: Adding zeros does not increase resolution.  Instead, it increases windowing artifacts for any signal that was integer periodic in the original sample vector.

Comment: @ hotpaw2 i read in the book that if one want to decrease the value of fs/N where fs is sampling rate/frequency and N is no. of samples, then there are two ways one is windowing and other is padding zeroes.So adding zeroes will increase the no. of samples and hence fs/N reduces